# Which method to separate a long message?

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing problem when receiving a long message as below

> 40=1.22.50=0.002.60=35.

The system use the dot as separator while there is also decimal values for numeric value.

The desired output is

> 40=1.22
>   50=0.002
>   60=35

I am now using manual way to format the message. Hope to have a better way to overcome this.

Comment: see my answer and code below

Comment: Is the bit on the left of the equals always an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one dot **"."** as the decimal position, and another **"."** that separates each element in the array. You can use the code below to read all values of the Long string into an array (`Nums` is the name of the array).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Seperate_DecimNumbers()

Dim Nums As Variant
Dim FullStr As String
Dim DotPosition As Integer
Dim i As Integer

' init array size to a large size , will redim it at the end to number of elements found
ReDim Nums(1 To 100)

FullStr = "40=1.22.50=0.002.60=35."

i = 1 ' init array elements counter
Do Until Len(FullStr) = 0
    ' call FindN function , searching for the 2nd "."
    DotPosition = FindN(FullStr, ".", 2)

    ' unable to find 2 "." in the string >> last element in the array
    If DotPosition = 0 Then
        Nums(i) = FullStr
        Exit Do
    Else ' was able to find 2 "." in the string
        Nums(i) = Left(FullStr, DotPosition - 1)
    End If

    i = i + 1
    FullStr = Right(FullStr, Len(FullStr) - DotPosition)
Loop

' redim array back to maximum of numbers found in String
ReDim Preserve Nums(1 To i)   

' place output start location from Range A2 and below (till number of elements in the array)
Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(Nums), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Nums)

End Sub



Function FindN(sInputString As String, sFindWhat As String, N As Integer) As Integer
' this function find the Nth position of a certain character in a string    

Dim J As Integer

Application.Volatile
FindN = 0

For J = 1 To N
    FindN = InStr(FindN + 1, sInputString, sFindWhat)
    If FindN = 0 Then ' unable to find the 2nd "." >> last appearance
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function
```

See result below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on the answer, which splits things on the `=` rather than the `.`.  Doing it this way allows for input such as `40=1.22.50=0.002.60=35.70=120`.  (i.e. the part to the right of an `=` does not **have** to contain a `.`, it could be an integer.)

```
Sub SplitDotEqual()
    Dim s As String
    Dim a() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    'Read from A1
    s = Range("A1").Value
    'Split on the "="
    a = Split(s & ".", "=") ' include an extra "." to ensure that
                            ' the final field is ended
    For i = 0 To UBound(a) - 1
        'Put the "=" back
        a(i) = a(i) & "="
        'Find the last "." before the next "="
        d = InStrRev(a(i + 1), ".")
        'Append everything prior to the "."
        a(i) = a(i) & Left(a(i + 1), d - 1)
        'Write to A2:Ax
        Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = a(i)
        'Strip off everything prior to the ".",
        'leaving just the stuff prior to the "="
        a(i + 1) = Mid(a(i + 1), d + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that **every other** dot is a separator.  This code changes the odd-numbered dots into pipes and then parses on the pipes:

```
Sub parser()
    Dim FlipFlop As Boolean, dot As String, pipe As String
    Dim s As String, L As Long, i As Long, CH As String

    dot = "."
    pipe = "|"
    s = Range("A1").Value
    L = Len(s)
    FlipFlop = True

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH = dot Then
            If FlipFlop Then
            Else
                Mid(s, i, 1) = pipe
            End If
            FlipFlop = Not FlipFlop
        End If
    Next i

    msg = s & vbCrLf
    ary = Split(s, pipe)
    For Each a In ary
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & a
    Next a
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How to make the result in the same excel sheet instead of msg box?

Comment: got more closer message and above code partially works

Answer (score 0):

got more closer message and the code partially works.

> 8=TEST.1.2.9=248.35=D.49=MMUIJ.56=FGTUH.34=32998.50=MMTHUJ.57=AY/ABCDE.52=20161216-07:58:07.11=00708991.1=A-12345-